# Erase in C# forms graphic?

Tags: c#, forms, graphics, erase

So I want to add an erase feature to my forms paint application. How would I go about doing this (i already have a "clear all" feature, I want to basically have a brush type thing that would erase instead of draw, and no, I don't want to just add a white colour because I want to erase to be bigger than the draw tool) pls help, thx!

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Simplified_Ms.Paint
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Graphics g;
        int x = -1;
        int y = -1;
        bool moving = false;
        Pen pen;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
            pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 5);
            g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            pen.StartCap = pen.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round;

        }

        private void panel2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            moving = true;
            x = e.X;
            y = e.Y;
            panel1.Cursor = Cursors.Cross;

        }

        private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (moving && x != -1 && y != -1)
            {
                g.DrawLine(pen, new Point(x, y), e.Location);
                x = e.X;
                y = e.Y;
            }

        }

        private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            moving = false;
            x = -1;
            y = -1;
            panel1.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PictureBox p = (PictureBox)sender;
            pen.Color = p.BackColor;
            moving = true;



        }

        private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PictureBox p = (PictureBox)sender;
            pen.Color = p.BackColor;
            moving = true;


        }

        private void pictureBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PictureBox p = (PictureBox)sender;
            pen.Color = p.BackColor;

            moving = true;


        }

        private void pictureBox4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PictureBox p = (PictureBox)sender;
            pen.Color = p.BackColor;
            moving = true;


        }

        private void pictureBox5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PictureBox p = (PictureBox)sender;
            pen.Color = p.BackColor;
            moving = true;

        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: "erase to be bigger than the draw tool", uh, just eraser = new Pen(Color.White, 10); then?

Comment: You need to learn the basic of gdi+ drawing,. I'm afraid you got it all wrong. - Never use `control.CreateGraphics`! Never try to cache a `Graphics` object! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter..


You can test the persistance of your graphics by doing a Minimize/Maximize sequence..

The correct way is to keep a list of things to draw and whenever that list changes `Invalidate` the control you draw on. All drawing should be in the `Paint` event, using `e.Graphics` there!